# SSIS - Why does import from excel file includes all n possible rows?

Tags: ssis

So I have an excel file with two columns, and about 400 rows in the excel file. However, when I read it to a database it brings in 1,048,451 rows, i.e I'm assuming the max amount of rows that excel allows.

Why could this be an issue? Is it just due to the file itself? I tried unchecking the "Retain null values from the source as null values in the data flow" option but that didn't make a difference. Plus, I would like to retain missing column values, just not include extra rows.

I could try and have an "Execute SQL Task" to just filter to get rid of all rows that are completely null, but is there a better way to fix this?

Comment: If you open the Excel file and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>, does it go to row 300 or 1M? If the latter, then it would seem there is "something" stored in those rows, even if it's empty. In those cases, add a Conditional Split to the import to look for data in Key Column X

Comment: @billinkc yes, I think you're right. A table was inserted into the Excel sheet, so that may be the cause of my problems. Just working around the issue may the best as you say, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else that stumbles across this post, as described by the comments, the problem was just that there was a table created in the excel worksheet that spanned the whole range. I simply got rid of that by modifying my workflow and inserting data into a staging table & then deleting all `NULL` rows in it.